# Trying to add global variables to a list instead of their assignments

Tags: python-3.x

The code is part of a bigger program. The Save function saves the global data (I know you shouldn't use global vars) and the Load function should load it and change the global vars to the loaded objects. I know lists only save the assigned objects and not the vars themselves, but I don't know how I can do this differently.
For the case, there is a solution which has to change the way I save the vars I also put the working Save function in the code.
Thanks for the help.

I searched for a solution on the internet and tried around with a few modules, but couldn't get anything to work.

```py
#works
def Save():
    global a, b, c, d, e
    toSave = [a, b, c, d, e]
    count = 0
    f = open("file.txt", "w") #file where the vars get saved and should be loaded from
    for x in range(len(toSave)):
        save = toSave[count]
        f.write(str(save)+"\n") #writes the objects the vars are assigned to into a file which each objekt having it's own row
        count += 1
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Save","Your progress got saved.")

def Load():
    global a, b, c, d, e
    toLoad = [a, b, c, d, e]
    count = 0
    f = open("file.txt", "r")
    for x in range(len(toLoad)):
        toLoad[count] = f.readline() #changes the numbers in the list. Should change the global vars
        count += 1
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Load","Your progress got loaded.")
```

I just want the global vars to become the saved objects, so I can load and save savefiles in my program (it's a small game).

Comment: You will get a syntax error on your open(file.txt), you need to wrap that in quotes, it's a string.

Comment: "I know you shouldn't use global vars": yes, that's the main issue here. Use a global list instead, that'll be an improvement. Or use a singleton object.

Comment: `global a, b, c, d, e
    toSave = [a, b, c, d, e]` => since those are strings, you cannot do anything to change the globals from there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explicitly assign data to the relevant variables:

1. Read all the values in a list, like you're doing in your code
2. Unpack the list: `a, b, c, d, e = the_list`

Or use a single global object that would hold the data:

```
GameState = {
 "level": 1,
 "player": {
  "health": .9,
  "strength": .2
 }
}
```

And then modify this single object from within your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Save it all as JSON data, and bring it back in as a dictionary, using that to load your global vars.

```
import json
#works
def Save():
    global a, b, c, d, e
    save_dict = {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'c': c,
        'd': d,
        'e': e
    }
    json_save_data = json.dumps(save_dict)
    with open('file.json' mode='w') as file:
        file.write(json_save_data)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Save","Your progress got saved.")

def Load():
    global a, b, c, d, e
    with open('file.json', "r") as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    global_dict = json.loads(data)
    a = global_dict['a']
    b = global_dict['b']
    c = global_dict['c']
    d = global_dict['d']
    e = global_dict['e']
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Load","Your progress got loaded."
```